# Is there a systematic way to determine the minimum rank of a quadratic form matrix such that the form's output doesn't change?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A$ (n x n) and a quadratic form $x^T A x$, I want to find a matrix $B$ with the lowest possible rank such that $x^T A x = x^T B x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$. My current method is adding various antisymmetric matrices to $A$ and eyeballing it until I get a matrix with a low rank. My main strategy is just lumping every bottom left entry with its top right associated entry and making as many $0$s as possible. I don't know if this is actually the lowest rank possible, though. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You should probably mention that you're considering matrices with real entries only

Comment: If $A$ is the symmetric matrix associated with the quadratic form, there is a [majorization relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) between the eigenvalues of $A$ and those of $B$, with $\operatorname{Re}[\lambda(B)] \prec \lambda(A)$. This, at the very least, places a limit on the lowest rank achievable for $B$

Comment: In particular, if $A$ has signature $(n_0,n_+,n_-)$, then the rank of $B$ is necessarily larger than $|n_+-n_-|$.

Comment: Can you explain how you got that last result?